# How to design a database of flight search for stoppages?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to design a database for flight say I want to travel to the USA from INDIA now the stoppages that come are like 1st) **Kolkata -> Mumbai -> London**

Now I want to design the database in such a way so I want can always search for Kolkata to London I can find that including Mumbai and also I can find it when searching for Mumbai to London. I am not able to figure out how to design the tables.

I am new to SQL and I have figured out something like this also earlier

**| flight id | flight_from | flight_to | stoppage1 |      time    |**  
        1               Kolkata       London    Mumbai      3:30pm

Now i know this is ridiculously childish to add stoppage in the same table as I can understand it needs to be inserted into other table but i can't find out the way out

Even if i want to add two or more stopages in between to show the order as Kolkata -> Mumbai -> Delhi -> London like this. Also how can make that happen so that if i search in between i can get the flight_to -- flight_to

**Any recommendations or suggestions is highly appreaciated.*

Comment: I didn't know there is a LONDON in USA - learned something there - and you should use the airport codes rather than their full names.

Comment: And there is a Usa, Japan.  It gives a new meaning to "Made in USA".

Comment: There are 5 airports serving Los Angeles.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a hurry and I didn't check the routes its just an example and we are all here in StackOverflow for concept and not what we are writing right !

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky.

What you see as a "flight" (and may be marketed as such by your airline) is probably a composition of flights, which is bundled together for convenience. This makes sense, because - theoretically - you can fly from any place in the world to any other place in the world, with hundreds, thousands or even millions of different combinations.

So, typically this is modelled using "flight" (e.g. "Kolkata->Mumbai") and "trip" ("Kolkdata->Mumbai->London").

Your search then becomes a network traversal question: Find all routes from Kolkata to London, where the gap between legs is shorter than x hours.

Leaving out all the metadata, you might set your flights up like so:

```
create table flight(
flight_id int not null, 
from_airport varchar(5) not null, 
to_airport varchar(5) not null, 
start_time datetime not null, 
  end_time datetime not null);
  
  
  insert into flight
  values
(1, 'KOL', 'MUM', '2021-01-01 00:00:01', '2021-01-01 02:00:01'), 
(2, 'KOL', 'MUC', '2021-01-01 03:00:01', '2021-01-01 08:00:01'), 
(3, 'MUM', 'KOL', '2021-01-01 04:00:01', '2021-01-01 06:00:01'), 
(4, 'KOL', 'MUC', '2021-01-01 05:00:01', '2021-01-01 12:00:01'), 
(5, 'MUM', 'LHR', '2021-01-01 05:00:01', '2021-01-02 02:00:01'), 
(6, 'MUM', 'LHR', '2021-01-03 05:00:01', '2021-01-02 02:00:01'), 
(7, 'MUM', 'LHR', '2020-01-03 05:00:01', '2021-01-02 02:00:01'), 
(8, 'MUM', 'LAX', '2021-01-01 05:00:01', '2021-01-02 02:00:01');
```

To find flights from KOL to LHR, you would write queries like

```
-- Direct!
select *
from flight
where from_airport = 'KOL'
and to_airport = 'LHR';

-- one stopover
select *, second_leg.start_time - first_leg.end_time as layover_time
from flight first_leg
inner join flight second_leg
  on first_leg.to_airport = second_leg.from_airport
where first_leg.from_airport = 'KOL'
and second_leg.to_airport = 'LHR'
and first_leg.end_time < second_leg.start_time
AND second_leg.start_time - first_leg.end_time between 25000 and 45000;
```

You can extend this with 2 stop overs, but it's unlikely you'd have people happy to go for 3 stopovers.

Answer (score 0):

How about a two-table structure? `flight` and `flight_station`.

```
flight
flight_id  carrier       number
    1      Air India        123
    2      British Air      456

 flight_station
 flight_station_id  stop_number flight_id    station_icao      time
    1                    0              1         CCU          15:30
    2                    1              1         BOM          17:50
    3                    2              1         LHR          08:50
    4                    0              2         EWR          14:00
    5                    1              2         LHR          02:30
    6                    2              2         CCU          07:00
```

`stop_number` 0 means the originating point, and the largest `stop_number` for the flight means the terminating point.

You can also have a stations table.

```
station_icao       name              country
  BOM              Mumbai              IN
  CCU              Kolkata             IN
  EWR              Newark              US
  LHR              London Heathrow     GB
```

To find flights with legs from Mumbai to Kolkata you could do something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.flight_id
  FROM flight_station a
  JOIN flight_station b  
          ON b.stop_number > a.stop_number
         AND a.flight_id = b.flight_id
 WHERE a.station_icao = 'CCU' 
   AND b.station_icao = 'BOM'
```